# How can I fix "Permission Denied" on ftp_put() in php?

Tags: php, ftp

I'm getting permission denied messages when I try to upload a file:

```
Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Can't open that file: Permission denied in /home/kirby/public_html/members/upload_advanced.php on line 48
```

The file already exists, how do I enable ftp_put() to overwrite it.

Also, here's the upload code:

```
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, "www/logos/web_".$row[username].".jpg",
                                  "../logos/web_" . $row[username] . ".jpg",  FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: Make sure it is writable by the FTP user.

Comment: Give it the proper permissions?

Answer (score 2):

To enable write access you have to edit the /etc/vsftpd.conf file and uncomment the

```
#write_enable=YES
```

line, so it should read

```
write_enable=YES
```

Save the file and restart vsftpd with sudo service vsftpd restart.
https://askubuntu.com/a/410962

Comment: How do you know the author is using vsftpd and not another FTP daemon? At any rate, the question was asked in *2012*, so I sure as hell hope he fixed the problem by now ;-)